# Independent continuous random variables problem

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

I have some problem at how to determine if two random variables are independent or not. If X and Y are two continuous random variables and their join probability density function is listed below

$$
f(x,y) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{2}x^{3}e^{-xy-x}, x > 0, y > 0\\ 
0, otherwise
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

My Question is that intuitively that random variable X is independent of Y since X won't affect the value of Y, but I calculated $f_{X}(x)$ and $f_{Y}(y)$ and found that $f(x,y) \neq f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)$

I want to why random variables X and Y are look independent and either value won't affect the value of the other random variable, but they are dependent actually?

Thank you!!!!!

Comment: Why do you think that the value of $X$ will not affect the value of $Y$?

Comment: @drhab
Since the the value of X doesn't bother which value of Y, Y can be any value.

Comment: @HaohaoChang $$f(x,y)=\underbrace{xe^{-xy}\mathbf1_{y>0}}_{f_{Y\mid X}(y)}\,\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}x^2e^{-x}\mathbf1_{x>0}}_{f_X(x)}$$

Clearly distribution of $Y\mid X$ depends on $X$, so no question of independence.

Comment: Actually you are not answering my question, but just repeat what you think. Anyway, if $X=Y$ (ultimate dependence) and $X$ can take any value then also $Y$ can take any value. So the ability of $Y$ to take any value does not exclude the possibility of dependence. If there is no  PDF $f(x,y)$ that can be written as a product $g(x)h(y)$ then there is no independence.

Comment: @drhab Thank you for your answer. But I still get confused why X and Y are dependent in this case, can you point it out more generally, thank you for your help. I agree with you about X and Y is not independent if  the PDF $f(x,y)$ can't be written as a product $g(x)h(y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing e.g. $x=1$ we get $f(1,y)=\frac12e^{-y-1}$ for $y>0$ and $f(1,y)=0$ otherwise.

For some constant $c$ this function equalizes $c\cdot f_Y(y\mid X=1)$ where $f_Y(y\mid X=1)$ denotes the PDF of $Y$ under condition $X=1$.

If we do the same for $x=2$ we get $f(2,y)=8e^{-2y-2}$ for $y>0$ and $f(1,y)=0$ otherwise.

For some constant $d$ this function equalizes $d\cdot f_Y(y\mid X=2)$ where  $f_Y(y\mid X=2)$ denotes the PDF of $Y$ under condition $X=2$.

Evidently the functions are of different shape which makes clear that $f_Y(y\mid X=1)$ and $f_Y(y\mid X=2)$ are definitely not the same.

Apparantly under condition $X=1$ the distribution of $Y$ differs from the distribution of $Y$ under condition $X=2$.

So the value that is taken by $X$ affects the distribution of $Y$.

This observation is enough to conclude that $Y$ and $X$ are not independent.